# using pandas dataframe multiply & add each row based on each year on a group by condition user_id & customer_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

am having pandas dataframe, it has 7 columns customer_id, user_id, year_month, values, 01,02,03 i have to multiply & add each row based on group by customer_id, user_id considering month from year_month column

```
Input Dataframe 
df
###
    customer_id  user_id year_month   values  01     02   03   
1     2285          1    2020-01       1000   45     81    0   
2     2285          1    2020-02       2000   18     18    05  
3     2285          1    2020-03       6000   06      18   0   

4     2285          2    2020-01       1800   45     81    0    
5     2285          2    2020-02       2700   18     18    05   
6     2285          2    2020-03       3600   06     18    0    

7     2285          1    2019-01       6300   45     81    0    
8     2285          1    2019-02       7200   18     18    05   
9     2285          1    2019-03       8100   06     18    0    

10    2285          1    2021-01      7272   45     81    0    
11    2285          1    2021-02      6366   18     18    05   
12    2285          1    2021-03      5544   06     18    0    

Expected Output Dataframe
df 
   customer_id    user_id date_month     volume     output_value
1  2285             1      2020-01       1000       207000
2  2285             1      2020-02       2000       84000
3  2285             1      2020-03       6000       42000

4   2285            2      2020-01       1800       207000
5   2285            2      2020-02       2700       84000
6   2285            2      2020-03       3600       42000
```

sample calculation should be done based on each month from date_month column for id -1 --> calculation will be

```
   01 (1000 *45 +2000*81+ 6000*0) =207000
   02 (1000 *18 +2000*18+ 6000*05) = 84000
   03 (1000 *06 +2000*18+ 6000*0) = 42000
```

i have tried below code to achieve the output_value column but am facing errors with

```
cols = pd.Series(["jan", "feb", "mar"])

# Pivot the "volume" column so it lines up with the "jan", "feb", "mar" columns
volumes = (
    df.assign(month=df["date_month"].str[-2:])
    .pivot(index="id", columns="month", values="volume")
    .set_axis(cols, axis=1)
)

# Line up the 2 frames
tmp = pd.concat(
    [df.set_index("id")[cols], volumes], axis=1, keys=["value", "volume"]
)

# Calculation
df["output"] = (tmp["value"] * tmp["volume"]).sum(axis=1).to_numpy()

# ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No so straightforward, there are 3 layers to achieve (pivoting, multiplying with MultiIndex, merging).

You can use:

```
df2 = df['year_month'].str.split('-', expand=True)

df['year'] = df2[0]

out = df.merge(
 df.set_index(['customer_id', 'user_id', 'year', 'year_month'])
   .mul(df.assign(month=df2[1])
          .pivot(index=['customer_id', 'user_id', 'year'], columns='month', values='values')
        )
   .sum(1)
   .rename('output_value')
   .reset_index(),
    how='left', on=['customer_id', 'user_id', 'year', 'year_month']
)
```

output:

```
    customer_id  user_id year_month  values  01  02  03  year  output_value
0          2285        1    2020-01    1000  45  81   0  2020      207000.0
1          2285        1    2020-02    2000  18  18   5  2020       84000.0
2          2285        1    2020-03    6000   6  18   0  2020       42000.0
3          2285        2    2020-01    1800  45  81   0  2020      299700.0
4          2285        2    2020-02    2700  18  18   5  2020       99000.0
5          2285        2    2020-03    3600   6  18   0  2020       59400.0
6          2285        1    2019-01    6300  45  81   0  2019      866700.0
7          2285        1    2019-02    7200  18  18   5  2019      283500.0
8          2285        1    2019-03    8100   6  18   0  2019      167400.0
9          2285        1    2021-01    7272  45  81   0  2021      842886.0
10         2285        1    2021-02    6366  18  18   5  2021      273204.0
11         2285        1    2021-03    5544   6  18   0  2021      158220.0
```

##### alternative format with `jan/feb/mar` as column names

The logic is the same, you just need to ensure the mapping is correct

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'])

df['year'] = s.dt.year

print(df.merge(
 df.set_index(['customer_id', 'user_id', 'year', 'year_month'])
   .mul(df.assign(month=s.dt.strftime('%b').str.lower())
          .pivot(index=['customer_id', 'user_id', 'year'], columns='month', values='values')
        )
   .sum(1)
   .rename('output_value')
   .reset_index(),
    how='left', on=['customer_id', 'user_id', 'year', 'year_month']
))
```

output:

```
    customer_id  user_id year_month  values  jan  feb  mar  year  output_value
0          2285        1    2020-01    1000   45   81    0  2020      207000.0
1          2285        1    2020-02    2000   18   18    5  2020       84000.0
2          2285        1    2020-03    6000    6   18    0  2020       42000.0
3          2285        2    2020-01    1800   45   81    0  2020      299700.0
4          2285        2    2020-02    2700   18   18    5  2020       99000.0
5          2285        2    2020-03    3600    6   18    0  2020       59400.0
6          2285        1    2019-01    6300   45   81    0  2019      866700.0
7          2285        1    2019-02    7200   18   18    5  2019      283500.0
8          2285        1    2019-03    8100    6   18    0  2019      167400.0
9          2285        1    2021-01    7272   45   81    0  2021      842886.0
10         2285        1    2021-02    6366   18   18    5  2021      273204.0
11         2285        1    2021-03    5544    6   18    0  2021      158220.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the customer_id as the index, but that one is not unique, pandas cannot handle non-unique multi-Indices. If you flatten the dataframe you will get rid of the multi-index and create a unique index at the same time.
If you change the code as follows it should run:

```
tmp = pd.concat(
    [df.set_index("id")[cols], volumes], axis=1, keys=["value", "volume"]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```